# minimum of dependent random variables

Tags: probability, probability-theory, probability-distributions

can someone give me a hint with following problem.

Need to find PDF of  $X-\min(Y,Z)$, where only available info is that $X,Y,Z$ are iid. Or, in other words PDF of minimum of two dependent variables: $\min(X-Y,X-Z)$.

Thanks!

Comment: Where is this from? (no other assumption whatsoever is given on the domain, distribution or properties of $X,Y,Z$?)

Comment: Besides being iid, they have zero mean and finite variance. Nothing else is known.

Comment: @user222763: I've been working on your problem with not much success. I did not find an interesetig result, only complicated 3D integrals. If you happened to have found some interesting answer then pls. share it with me.